# Getting Nested values in angular with a json feed

Tags: angularjs

I have the following json example:

```
posts: [
    {
       title: Post Title,
     - cat: [
            - {
                name: "Category Name",
              }
            ],
```

I am able to get the title in Angular using {{post.title}}

However when I try to get {{post.cat.name}} its not working and its returning "0"

Comment: try this {{post.cat[0].name}}

Comment: Its not working still getting 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `cat` is an `array`. You should handle it like that.

`{{posts.cat[0].name}}` if you want the first element in that array.

Usually for arrays you'll use `ng-repeat` though:

```
<span ng-repeat="cat in posts.cat">{{cat.name}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
  $scope.posts=[
    {
       title: "Post Title",
       cat: [
           {
                name: "Category Name",
           }
          ]
    },
     {
       title: "Post Title2",
       cat: [
           {
                name: "Category Name2",
           }
          ]
    }
  
  ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   
  <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="p in posts" >
       
         <td >{{p.title}}</td>
         <td >{{p.cat[0].name}}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is an array, so to get the `name` of the first object in that array, you would have to use:

`{{post.cat[0].name}}`